# I just started guitar this week, frets buzzing

Tags: guitar

I am new to guitar and I can't play for crap, but I have noticed something. If my find touch the fret at all it buzzes. I am only using the tips of my fingers and pressing down the string all the way but If my fingers tips touch the fret it buzzes. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Place your fingers in the position behind the metal fret. The gap. This should stop the buzzing. If it doesn't then your guitar may be broken. Btw, if you reword the question to make what you are asking clearer you might even get a proper answer...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to know if that's normal. Yes, it is.If your finger touches a fret then that string is likely to buzz or sound muffled. You should try to get your fingers as close behind the fret as you can without touching it (although in some chord shapes it's not possible to get particularly close behind the fret, so for the moment just make sure you are fingering between the frets, not on the frets).

You might also get a buzz or dampened sound if you are not pressing the string firmly enough. This is most likely to happen on barre chords in low positions. A lot of older guitar tutorials teach learners the chord of F major in the first position quite early on. This is a very challenging chord for a beginner to play clearly. The advantage of learning it early is that you start building muscle strength, the disadvantage is that you might get discouraged. Don't get discouraged! It will come in time, and there is a lot you can do with easier chords.